# How is bootstrapping used in machine learning?

Tags: bootstrap, bagging

I understood bootstrapping in the statistical context.

Example: we have a sample of 1000 people. We want to know their mean. We pick 5 people at random (with replacement) for 20 times and we compute the mean of the 5 people for each extraction. We end up with 20 means and we can have an estimate of the real mean and of its error. Is this correct?

I was following an online course of machine learning and neural networks. The professor briefly mentioned bootstrapping. How would you use it in the context of machine learning?

I know how bagging is used (ensembles), but I am not sure how plain bootstrapping would be used.

Comment: The duplicate answers your first question, "is this correct?".  The short answer is no.

Comment: I read the duplicated question, but it's not clear to me why the example above would not be correct.
Also, I am not sure why my question was labeled as duplicated since I am trying to understand how bootstrapping is used in machine learning (not in plain statistics). 
Of course, if I didn't understand it in the statistical context, I'd be happy to understand why :) 
Thank you!

Comment: You describe a form of *resampling,* but not *bootstrapping.*  The nature of your distinction between stats and ML is obscure: bootstrapping is the same procedure no matter what you call yourself!

Comment: Ok, got it. But is my resampling at least a particular example of bootstrapping?
Oh, so here's my confusion: when speaking about statistics we usually want to estimate a parameter. How about ML? Why would we use bootstrapping? To estimate the error of the model? If yes, in practice, how?

Comment: Your resampling does not appear to be an example.  It's fundamental that the bootstrap resample is obtained from the original sample with replacement and *is the same size.* Please see some of our [posts on bootstrapping](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bootstrap+score%3A5+is%3Aanswer).  Your characterization of statistics is way, way, too narrow.  Exploring [some of our more popular posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A20+is%3Aanswer) will help give you some sense of just a few procedures and concepts of statistics.